# How to make GUI apps running from docker look pretty under Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, user-interface, ubuntu

I built a docker image to run Sublime-Text3 from [GitHub](https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/tree/master/sublime-text-3), because eventually I want to have all my GUI apps that I use for development be available from a docker image. I run it on Ubuntu 18. Ubuntu runs on virtual machine (Virtual Box) which runs on Mac computer.

Everything works but Sublime looks like an app running under Windows 95, in other words it looks [horrible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0xTP.jpg). So I thought that maybe installing Gtk themes will help. I installed another theme and changed it in the built-in Customize Look and Feel app from Ubuntu but the GUI of Sublime didn't change at all. I then tried changing the theme from `gtk-chtheme` which didn't help either.

These are the commands I ran in terminal before docker container start:

```
$ xhost local:root

$ docker run -d -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -e NEWUSER=$USER sublime-text:3
```

Is it possible to make GUI apps whose docker image is built on debian without GUI have "pretty" appearance in the host OS?

Comment: Don't know if it helps but I used docker run -d \
--net host \
--cpuset-cpus 0 \
--memory 512mb \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
-e DISPLAY=unix:0 \
--device /dev/snd \
-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm \ for gui apps

Comment: @lvthillo thanks but that didn't help